# The exchange rate is [ boring ]

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a blog post and found the sentence "The exchange rate is boring."

Can I use the adjective 'boring' for the word 'rate'?
If possible, what will it[boring] mean in the above sentence?

Comment: It means the subject of the rate is boring, perhaps because the rate changes so little as not to be a topic of much appeal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use boring to describe an *exchange rate*, notice that the word *boring* is modifying *exchange rate* and not simply *rate* here.

## boring

> Not interesting or exciting:
> ([Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/boring))

Without additional context the meaning is ambiguous, and could mean either of the following: -

**The speaker finds exchange rates generally uninteresting**

The *exchange rate* might be uninteresting because the person that stated that the exchange rate was *boring* generally finds financial markets boring and are bored by financial indices in general.

**The exchange rate is relatively stable**

A second meaning would be that the exchange rate of the currency in question is relatively stable, it is not undergoing large swings in either direction (up or down) and therefore is relatively uninteresting to observe.